# Meteor JS, running in a debugger?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm curious if anyone has a solution for running meteor in a debugger. I have some experience with running regular node in a debugger, have used JetBrains Webstorm for this, however it doesn't seem to support meteor (as far as I can tell). If anyone has a solution, would appreciate any information. It seems, eventually this will need to be possible for meteor to become a longterm viable platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the meteor startup script does not support a debugging option at this point, but you can fix this yourself:

Open the meteor startup script in a text editor (use  `which meteor` to find it)

Change the last line (add $NODE_DEBUG parameter):

`exec "$DEV_BUNDLE/bin/node" $NODE_DEBUG "$METEOR" "$@"`

Now you can launch meteor in debug mode like this:

`NODE_DEBUG=--debug meteor`

Comment: How did you setup the webstorm debug configuration?

Comment: Future viewers please upvote this http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264#tab=Comments